# Trying to find out what's wrong with the laptop after supposed Windows 10 update?

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop

[image]

The details of this issue are blurry simply because I wasn't present at the time of its occurrence. From what I was told, my 10 year old cousin brother attempted to update their Lenovo laptop to Windows 10 on his own and I believe the download may have failed?

Regardless of the circumstances, the above image shows up on the monitor screen display and I just want to know how we can recover use of the laptop and if it is possible to do so while saving all data and documents contained.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but I'd recommend: (1) create a Live USB of some form of Linux, (2) boot the laptop from the USB, (3) copy whatever data  you need from the laptop's hard drive to a separate, external hard drive, and then (4) once the data is safe, attempt to troubleshoot.

Comment: How do I create a live USB? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Disclaimer: if you're not comfortable with computers (no shame! :-) ), this may not be advisable...there's a risk of doing significant damage to your data (not the physical laptop) if you aren't careful. In that case, consider contacting Lenovo or finding a friend who's good with computers. That said: [this link](https://answers.syr.edu/display/os/How+to+Recover+Data+with+Linux) gives as good a step-by-step guide as any on how to recover your data. Focus on using the GUI - do NOT use the terminal/command line unless you know what you're doing!

Answer (score 0):

This **should** be simple.

1. Get 8gb USB blank, or back it up and make it blank
2. Microsoft.com get the Media Creation Tool
3. Insert USB
4. Install Media Creation Tool
5. Launch and make the USB stick into a bootable media
6. Boot the PC from USB, but there is a small link for **Repair PC**

Use the repair choice to do the automatic repair.  That usually fixes it for me, as I have had this error numerous times.  On rare occasion you have to goto the command prompt from there and redo the bootloader.